# How to fix undefined method `path_for' for #<ActiveStorage::Service::PostgreSQLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm setting up an account profil system and i want to support an avatar with active_storage in my rails app.
I'm expecting to see my avatar but instead i've got this[broken_pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNo0A.png)

If i open the picture in an other tabs he send me this  app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb line 10-17:

```
def show
if key = decode_verified_key
  serve_file disk_service.path_for(key[:key]), content_type: key[:content_type], disposition: key[:disposition]
else
  head :not_found
end
```

end
the problem come from this line or above `serve_file disk_service.path_for(key[:key]), content_type: key[:content_type], disposition: key[:disposition]`

Comment: This question and the formatting are very confusing. What is your actual issue here? What do you hope to accomplish? You have thrown a lot of information onto the screen but I am not sure it is cohesive and I am not sure that I follow.

Comment: Sorry first time using stackoverflow i will re work my question

Comment: You should "accept" the answer that solved your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just had this same issue. Turns out the implementation of  ActiveStorage::DiskController#show changed from Rails 5.2.1 to Rails 5.2.2. See [5.2.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1.1/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb#L12) vs [5.2.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.2/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/disk_controller.rb#L10)

The `active_storage-postgresql` gem relied on the behaviour of Rails 5.2.1. It looks like there is a [PR that has just been merged to fix this](https://github.com/lsylvester/active_storage-postgresql/pull/6), so I expect there will soon be a new release of the gem to restore Rails compatibility. Keep an eye on https://rubygems.org/gems/active_storage-postgresql .

As a temporary fix, we added a controller action like so to download the blobs via [`send_file`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file).

```rb
def download_file
  attachment = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
  file = attachment.blob
  data = file.download
  send_data(data, type: file.content_type, filename: file.filename, disposition: "inline")
end

# then call like 
download_file_path(model.file.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

@user10981734's answer worked for me. I was actually able to boil it down to something more concise:

```
file = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id]).blob

send_data(
  file.download,
  type: file.content_type,
  filename: File.basename(file.filename.to_s)
)
```